# How do I use my first row in my spreadsheet for my Dataframe column names instead of 0 1 2...etc?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want my dataframe to display the first row names as my dataframe column name instead of numbering from 0 etc. How do I do this?

I tried using pandas and openpyxl modules to turn my Excel spreadsheet into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = load_workbook(filename='Budget1.xlsx')
print(wb.sheetnames)
sheet_ranges=wb['May 2019']
print(sheet_ranges['A3'].value)

ws=wb['May 2019']
df=pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
print(df) # This displays my dataframe.
```

I expect my column titles of my dataframe to display Date, Description, and Amount instead of 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading data dataframe using pandas you can separate first row then use that as column name:

```
columnNames = df.iloc[0] 
df = df[1:] 
df.columns = columnNames
```

Or, you can directly read using pandas that will set first row as column name:

```
excelDF = pd.ExcelFile('Budget1.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(excelDF, 'SheetNameThatYouWantTORead')
print(df1.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reset the columns to be the first row of your dataframe:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx", sheetname='xyz', header=0, skiprows=[0])

header=0 will read first row as header while skiprows will let you skip first row as data